# Is it possible to debug both client and server code in I.E?

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging

I have been using Chrome or Firebug throughout my development because I cannot figure out how to debug both the client and server side code using I.E. Is this even possible? If so, how? If not, any workarounds?

Comment: I don't believe that is possible. Even on the same machine, IE is not acting as a web server. IIS is the server side piece serving up the content. Why not just debug the server side code in whatever debugger you would use for that language? What language/stack are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does have a debugger that functions similar to Firebug and Chrome debugger. You can get it by clicking settings->F12 developer tools. 
However, server codes are never delivered to the client side, so the browsers can't even see them, not to mention debugging. This is true for all 3 browsers you mentioned. 
Why not use some backend IDE for server code debugging? Eclipse & NetBeans are both excellent choices.